# Transpose, Slice and Inject From Multipe Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't know how appropriate title for this question.

Well, This is my problem

I have `index` action on `homes_controller.rb` looks like :

```
def index
  @r = 2
  @datas = [[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 15], [4, 20], [5, 70], [6, 180], [7, 250], [8, 270], [9, 230], [10, 40], [11, 0], [12, 10]]
end
```

I want to result from above like this:

[image: i want]

And on view looks like :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Forecast</th>
     <th>Order</th>
     <th>Begining Inventory</th>
     <th>Ending Inventory</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <% ei = 0 %>
   <% @datas.each_with_index do |d, index| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= d[0] %></td>
     <td><%= d[1] %></td>
     <td><% if d[1] > bi %>
      <% @datas.transpose.at(1).slice(index, @r).inject do |sum, s| -%>
       <%= @biu = sum + s %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
     </td>
     <td><%= @bi = ei + @biu %></td>
     <td><%= @ei = @bi - d[1]  %></td>
    </tr>
   <% @biu = 0 %>
   <% ei = @ei %>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

State :

1. When the forecast `d[1]` is bigger than `ei` the calculation order `@biu` is 2 (`@r`) next of forecast.
2. Begining Inventory `@bi` is calculation from `ei` plus order `@biu`
3. Ending Inventory `@ei` is calculation from `@bi`subtracted with forecast `d[1]`
4. And then `@ei` put to `ei`

But the result like this :

[image: result]

I want 12th months must have : Order = 10, Begining invetory = 10, and Ending Inventory = 0

Comment: Could you state in words what exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<% @datas.transpose.at(1).slice(index, @r).inject do |sum, s| -%>
  <%= @biu = sum + s %>
<% end %>
```

When an array has only one item, `inject` without a starting value does not run the block at all:

```
puts [1,2].inject { |sum, s| puts 'was here!'; sum + s }
# was here!
# 3

puts [1].inject { |sum, s| puts 'was here!'; sum + s }
# 1

puts [1].inject(0) { |sum, s| puts 'was here!'; sum + s }
# was here!
# 1
```

If you add a starting value `0` to your code, though, `@biu` will be printed twice. To avoid that you need to move the assignment outside of the block:

```
<% @biu = @datas.transpose.at(1).slice(index, @r).inject do |sum, s| -%>
  <% sum + s %>
<% end %>
<%= @biu %>
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
<%= @biu = @datas.transpose.at(1).slice(index, @r).inject(:+) %>
```